# gbp buildpackage for some reason includes home dir

Tags: git, package, debian

I‘m trying to create a .deb package using git buildpackage as described here: http://www.lpenz.org/articles/debgit/index.html

Basically, this works fine, the package is built and I can install and uninstall, no problem. But for some reason, my home dir (which is where I build it), is included in the package (just the directory structure up to the build dir, not the contents).

So, if I look at the package contents with „dpkg -c“, the first entry is „/home/wiggy/git/packagesource“. This results in a) lintian complaining that files from my home dir are included in the package, and b) a warning message during uninstallation of the package „Not deleting /home/wiggy since it‘s not empty.“

There‘s nothing in the „install“ target in the Makefile that installs anything into my home dir, and everything in the package is installed correctly where it‘s supposed to be (/usr/bin, /usr/share and so on), so I guess there must be some command line of config option that I‘m missing.

WHat can cause the build dir to be included in the package during building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the reason: In the Makefile for the software I'm builing, there's a step where a Copyright-file is generated from a template (the correct years ia automatically added). This file is generated in the build dir and is then later installed in the INSTALL target.

I guess that gbp somehow detects that there is a file generated in the build dir and interprets this as an installation command or something, even though it does then not include this temporary file in the package.

Removing the auto-generation of this file from the Makefile fixed it.